# ssh-add: add_file: key_cert_copy: invalid argument

Tags: ssh, linux-mint, ssh-agent

I get this error when running ssh-add. The command seems to work after this, but the return code is 127 (so a script runs into an error at this point). Does anyone recognize the error? Google doesn't seem to.

```
$ eval `ssh-agent`
Agent pid 19527

$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/my_id_rsa
Enter passphrase for /home/davidparks21/.ssh/my_id_rsa: 
Identity added: /home/davidparks21/.ssh/my_id_rsa (/home/davidparks21/.ssh/my_id_rsa)
add_file: key_cert_copy: invalid argument
```

---

Added details

```
ssh -v localhost
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016

ssh-add ./id_rsa                                   # No passphrase
Identity added: ./id_rsa (./id_rsa)
add_file: key_cert_copy: invalid argument
```

Odd note: when I ran this test and `echo $?` to check the exit status I see an exit status of `0`, different from what I saw when I originally wrote this question.

Comment: Which operating system ?

Comment: Linux Mint 18.3 / Ubuntu 16.04, added to the tags.

Comment: And which version of `ssh[-agent]`?

Comment: A bug has been reported for Windows where it throws error for keys with paraphrase and works with the one for empty paraphrase https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/838

Comment: Can u try the same for a key with empty paraphrase ?

Comment: Added results of both queries to the question.

Comment: I haven't attempted to find the source code used to build the OpenSSH packages on your OS, but a from a quick reading of the tip of the master branch, there are two reasons you could see this error:  [either your pubkey is empty, or your pubkey has too many principals](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/sshkey.c#L1675-L1728).  It is also possible that the error is caused by a bug in the `sshkey_load_public` function.

Comment: Presumably if you execute `ssh-add -k ~/.ssh/id_whatever`, you don't get the error message?  And do you have a file with the naming convention of a corresponding certificate `~/.ssh/id_whatever-cert.pub` ?

Comment: That was it! My `.pub` files were named differently from the key file, there was an extra `-cert` added to them. When I renamed them to match the key file everything worked, and the `-k` option sidestepped the issue as well. Both of those comments are valid answers you guys can post.

Comment: @user4556274 make sure to grab that bounty.